# How, on VIFM, you can map a key to call the "=" (filter) function, without an initial query?

Tags: vifm

When you type "=" on VIFM, it starts with the last query as the initial query. I want it to start empty. How is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Put the following command into your `vifmrc` to achieve the desired behaviour of <kbd>=</kbd>:

```
nnoremap = =<c-u>
```

Some details so you know how to deal with something similar in future:

- The command maps `=` to `=<c-u>` sequence of keys.
- [`nnoremap`](http://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-%3Annoremap) instead of `nmap` is needed to prevent expansion of any keys in right-hand side (in case you map <kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd> in command-line mode to something else one day).
- [`<c-u>`](http://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-CTRL-U) key (notation for <kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd>) in command-line mode removes all characters from current position to the beginning of the line, just as in shell.
- As cursor is positioned at the end of the line `<c-u>` effectively clears the line.

Comment: Hello, I'm Viclib, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I can't accept it because SO requires me to "complete my signup" with the other login before so. But when I do it (which requires an absurdly restrictive password which I had to note down, making it much less safe than the one I had in mind), go to my email and click on the confirmation link, it says "email already registered" in plain text without anything else on the page at all. Effectively I'm half-logged in an account that can't vote nor register to a full-login because I apparently already used the email before. Sorry.